# Failed to align audio to transcript during adaptation

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to adapt the acoustic model for use with Sphinx4 with some of my own transcribed data. The data I am using for adaptation is 8kHz so I changed the params file in the original acoustic model (which used 16kHz audio) because I use it throughout the adaptation process:

```
-lowerf 200.00
-upperf 3500.00
-nfilt 31
-ncep 13
-transform legacy
-round_filters yes
-unit_area yes
-remove_dc no
-feat 1s_c_d_dd
```

Feature extraction appears to work fine but the Baum Welch is resulting in many errors.  For reference, the Baum Welch command line parameters are shown below:

```
-hmmdir ../hub4opensrc.cd_continuous_8gau -moddeffn ../hub4opensrc.cd_continuous_8gau/mdef.txt -ts2cbfn .cont. -feat 1s_c_d_dd -cmn current -agc none -dictfn ../adaptationData.dict -ctlfn ../adaptationData.listoffiles -lsnfn ../adaptationData.transcription -accumdir .
```

And the errors are the same for every file (one of which is shown below):

```
INFO: cmn.c(175): CMN:  9.69  0.13 -0.11 -0.13 -0.19 -0.23 -0.25 -0.19 -0.22 -0.19 -0.10 -0.09 -0.07 
ERROR: "backward.c", line 421: Failed to align audio to trancript: final state of the search is not reached
ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: sn74tiCEB6F7DE7672F ignored
utt>   233       sn74tiCEB6F7DE7672F  177    0   112 12  utt 0.000x 0.000e upd 0.000x 0.000e fwd 0.000x 0.000e bwd 0.000x 0.000e gau 0.000x 0.000e rsts 0.000x 0.000e rstf 0.000x 0.000e rstu 0.000x 0.000e
```

I'm very confused why the algorithm does not complete and am wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to how to overcome this if you have also run into this issue before.

Comment: check out this link http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt

Comment: The output is not from Sphinx4. What was the command you used for adaptation?

Comment: @AlexanderSolovets I am using the baum welch executable (on windows) as part of the model adaptation process.  Not necessarily Sphinx4 I suppose - it's actually packaged up with pocketsphinx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hub4 is 16khz acoustic model, you can not adapt it to recognize 8khz audio. You need to adapt narrow bandwidth acoustic model. For example you can adapt communicator continuous model from downloads or wsj_8khz model from sphinx4.

Comment: Thanks for this @Nikolay.  I grabbed the wsj_8khz model and started the adaptation process with this as my base acoustic model.  Still seeing the same error but haven't had time to look into it yet.  Will investigate more over the next two days.

Comment: Ok, feel free to provide the data to reproduce your problem if you have something specific.

Comment: I was able to successfully adapt a small percentage of the files that I wanted to adapt (6 of 235) using the wsj_8kHz model.  I am wondering if it could be an issue with the VAD algorithm (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/gstreamer#the_vader_element)?  In any event, I have posted two files (one that succeeds, one that fails) and all of the necessary information in the directory: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1dRatHiAwT5ZDNmTHgzMnJ3bDg&usp=drive_web

If you have any suggestions feel free to let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking on your files I see you didn't prepare them properly. I doubt you should focus on adaptaiton first, it seems that proper cleanup might be a more important thing. First of all you need make sure your files do not have zero-energy regions and finalizing white noise. They must be filtered with external software if you hope to apply speech recognition.